# Yup with Formik doesn't Datepicker value

Tags: javascript, datepicker, react-hooks, formik, yup

I have been trying everything to make this form work with yup, but when using the date-picker, the value doesn't register either within the field or with yup.
My relevant imports are formik, yup, useForm and yupResolver.

I have removed non-relevant code to save space. The other fields i have are first name, last name, email and phone number, and they all work as they should, with values registering and errors showing up when they don't fill the criteria.

I have a console log withing the formik element which logs all the values, and all the values get logged properly except the dates, which stand empty.

```js
const Form = () => {
    const [fromDate, setFromDate] = useState(new Date());

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <Formik validationSchema={formVal}>
                    {({ values,
                        errors) => ( 
                        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                            <div>
                                <DatePicker
                                    id="fromDate"
                                    onChange={(date) => {
                                        setFieldValue(date);
                                    }}
                                />
                            </div>
                            <Button type="submit" ></Button>
                        </form>
                )}
                </Formik>
            </div>
        </>
    )}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're not using 'setFieldValue' correctly;
The 1st argument should be the form's field name.

Should be something like this: setFieldValue('fromDate', date);
See https://formik.org/docs/api/formik for reference.

Also, make sure that variable 'date' is of type Date and not an object, containing the actual date value.

Comment: Yes this worked perfectly thank you! But yes i noticed the variable date is an object, how do i turn it into the Date type?

Comment: NP :) Try to explore the object, look for a property of type Date. Which Datepicker are you using? Is it of some UI library? Which one?

Comment: It gets printed out like this: 
fromDate: Thu Apr 29 2021 14:39:06 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
__proto__: Object

I am using DatePicker from react-datepicker